# RxJava2 switchIfEmpty and verifing an execution

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

so.. imagine I have a method construct like this:

LocalDatabase:

```
public Observable<PoiObject> getPoiObject() {

    return Observable.defer {
        PoiObject object = poiDao.getPoiObject();
        if(object == null) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
        else {
            return Observable.just(object);
        }
    }
}
```

now, I have another method somewhere else that goes like this:

Service:

```
public Observable<PoiObject> getPoiObject() {
    return localDatabase.getPoiObject()
}

public Observable<PoiObject> getItFromWeb() {
    return restService.getObject()
}
```

if I try to chain up the call of the Service::getPoiObject into a Rx call like this:

Usecase:

```
public Observable<SomeVM> getObject() {
    return service.getPoiObject()
        .switchIfEmpty(service.getItFromWeb())
}
```

Then the following unit test fails:

```
@Test
public void test_getObject() {
    Service service = mock()

    when(service.getPoiObject()).thenReturn(any());

    Observable<SomeVM> observable = usecase.getObject();
    verify(service).getPoiObject();
    verify(service, times(0)).getItFromWeb();
}
```

Why would getItFromWeb() execute when clearly,the previous call is not empty (object is returned from service.getPoiObject() call). Is there any other strategy to test upon switchIfEmpty?

Comment: You have to subscribe to `observable`.

Comment: jesus, for the purpose of the example I didn't put that part, of course I subscribe to the observable..

Comment: `getObject()` calls `getItFromWeb()` unconditionally when filling in the parameter of `switchIfEmpty()`.

Comment: are you trying to guess this? It's switch if empty construction that should execute only if the previous only is Observable.empty

Answer (score 8):

Opening a brace doesn't magically make the code/variable beyond it get initialized in a lazy manner. What you wrote is this:

```
public Observable<SomeVM> getObject() {
    Observable o1 = service.getPoiObject();
    Observable o2 = service.getItFromWeb();  // <-------------------
    Observable o3 = o1.switchIfEmpty(o2);
    return o3;
}
```

You already did the reasonable job in `getPoiObject()` by deferring execution, which you should apply in `getObject()` as well:

```
public Observable getObject() {
    return service.getPoiObject()
             .switchIfEmpty(Observable.defer(() -> getItFromWeb()));
}
```